# A little layout problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See attached picture (with meme-compliant hand-drawn circle).

My browser is IE8.

[image]

Comment: For me it also appears behind the "Ask Question" button on Gaming, but not elsewhere (of the sites I frequent). Althought, it's probably only wide enough to reach the button because of an IE7 problem.

Comment: I see it on *every* SE site I frequent.

Comment: Yes, I see your particular case on every site (ie, the question title bar) - but thought I'd add another situtation that I'd discovered where the same issue was occuring.

Comment: Oh, you were talking about the **button**... sorry, read it only now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in teh codez; just waiting to build