# Wrong favorite count in drop down

Tags: support, bookmarks

When I click on my name a drop down appears which shows reputation/revisions/favorites. But the count in favorites is wrong. When I click on favorites it shows correct page with correct count but the count in drop down is wrong.

[image]

Also on ask question page drop down is not proper:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not the *total number* of favorites, but the number *of changes* to the questions you favorited. This is updated just like [if you actually were the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84374/how-to-access-all-of-my-favorites/84387#84387) of the questions yourself.

(That is: when new comments or new answers were added, but not when answers have been modified.)

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [A little layout problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82612/a-little-layout-problem) in regards to the index of the elements, as for the first issue it seems to work perfectly for me.

Maybe a developer could take a look.

Comment: it still shows me wrong favorites count.

Comment: @Harry, so now you know why asking two questions in one post isn't the best thing to do ;-)